# how to autosize modal popup sharepoint in the link

Tags: popup, dialog

I m using

`<a onclick="javascript:SP.UI.ModalDialog.ShowPopupDialog('url')">`

But for some libraries, the size of pop up dialog is not large enough.

How to add the property width or auto Size without using custom function.

I cannot use functions because security disable script automatically but not in a link.

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 3):

You can use an alternative method [`showModalDialog`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/ff410058(v%3doffice.14)) for that purpose:

```
<a onclick="javascript:SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog({ autoSize: true, url: 'url' });">
```

Comment: I would always go with this as its recent and has more options